# Nuxt.js: weird behavior on two or more <nuxt-child> on same directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

in Nuxt, with this folder structure.

```
main
├── parent1
│   └── index.vue
├── parent2
│   └── index.vue
├── _parent1.vue
├── _parent2.vue
```

_parent1.vue and _parent2.vue contains `<nuxt-child>` tag inside and supposedly render the contents of parent1/index.vue parent2/index.vue contents respectively.

but... when accessing ~/main/parent1 and ~/main/parent2 route, both shows the content of _parent1.vue!!! or whichever component that comes first alphabetically.

is it a known bug? are there any solution to make is work as expected?

edit: added underscore to parent file

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on Nuxt 2.15.3. What's your Nuxt version? Can you modify this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxtlabs/examples/tree/master/routing/nested-pages?from-embed) to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @User28 thanks for the comment! I reviewed my code and there was a little diff between my post and my actual code so I edited my post. here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-meadow-fmhj1?file=/pages/parent/_child.vue) which reproduces my problem

Comment: @User28 actually thanks to your sample I was able to solve my problem, I just needed to remove the underscore prefix on my parent file. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can answer your own question. It may help other people.

Comment: Why are you even mixing `parent1/index.vue` and `_parent1.vue` (this one is not even dynamic, or is it somehow)? IMO, you should keep one or ther other but the 2 are doing the same thing as of right now. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-routes

Comment: @kissu parent1 and parent2 both have their own nav bar inside main's nav. looks somewhat like nested nav bar

Comment: Do you have a visual for this?